# soql contains on multiple values

Tags: soql, contains

I have accounts with billingcities.

I have a query like below,

```
select id , billingcity from account where billingcity like%atl%
```

If i want to search on multiple cities, how can I do this?
will comma seperated values work in like.

```
select id, billingcity from account where billingcity like%atl,por,bos%
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Collection of type String to find values using like:

```
String[] cities = 'atl%,por%,bos%'.split(',');
Account[] accounts = [select id, billingcity from account where billingcity like :cities];
```

Otherwise, you'd have to use the far more tedious method of building a query string:

```
select id, billingcity from account where billingcity like 'atl%' or billingcity like 'por%' or billingcity like 'bos%'
```

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox, it worked, i marked as best answer as I saw yours first. and thank you @santanu

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this:

```
Set<String> billingCityNames = new Set<String>{'%atl%', 'por%', 'bos%'};
select id, billingcity from account where billingcity like :billingCityNames
```

or you can use:

```
select id, billingcity from account where billingcity like '%atl' OR billingcity like '%por%' OR billingcity like 'bos%
```

Using of bind variable is more preferable in terms of secure coding practice.